# Unable to access website on Safari (iPhone) after renewing SSL certificate

Tags: iphone, safari, ssl-certificate

I have recently renewed the SSL certificate of my website, and everything works fine for most applications (including owncloud, git, ...), but not Safari on my iPhone (Firefox on my computer is fine).

Here is what exactly happens when I try to access my website (let's say `mysite.fr`) from Safari:

- I open the search bar, type `mysite.fr` (I tried `http://mysite.fr`, `https://mysite.fr`);
- I click `Go`;
- The loading bar appears on the top-left corner;
- The loading bar disappears (almost immediately);
- I am back on the page I was before - The page was not reload, it is as if I did nothing...

If someone could help me get access to my site back on my iPhone, I would really appreciate...

---

Extra information if necessary:

- iOS version: 10.2.
- The certificate is not self-signed, it comes from [startSSL](https://www.startssl.com/).

Comment: Time to open a support ticket with startSSL and ask what the difference is between the two certificates.

Comment: Did you perhaps use certificate pinning before?

Comment: @DanielB I don't know what this is actually - Maybe this is enable in my Nginx configuration (if I have understood correctly what this is... ), I have to check.

Comment: @Holt - You should do some research on the subject, come back, and then edit your question to include the requested information.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: See also: [StartSSL certificate gives SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE in Firefox and ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/startssl-certificate-gives-sec-error-revoked-certificate-in-firefox-and-err-cert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recent certs from StartSSL are suspect** because of misconduct by its new owner WoSign and [Firefox 51 is scheduled to distrust them in a few weeks](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/). Google says the same for Chrome 56.

Apple's announcement https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132 of Nov. 30 concludes

> We are taking further actions to protect users in an upcoming security update. Apple products will block certificates from WoSign and StartCom root CAs if the "Not Before" date is on or after 1 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT/UTC.

However, I would expect Safari to give a specific indication of the problem, not just return to a previous page. I can't help you with that part, but hopefully someone else can.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll try creating a self-signed certificate and see how Safari / Firefox react. And when I have time, I will switch to another Certificate Authority.

Comment: @Holt - I suggest you use some other device other then an iPhone to conduct those tests.  Self-signed certificates don't do well on iOS.

Comment: @Ramhound I would gladly use something else but my only problem here is Safari for iOS... Everything works fine (even my owncloud app on iOS... ) with my new certificate except Safari.

Comment: How recently did you renew the certificate.  If it was last year, and your using Firefox 51 and Chrome 56, then your certificate is still trusted even though it was issued by StartSSL

Comment: @Ramhound No, it was a few days ago. The above clearly applies to my certificate, but I don't use Firefox 51 yet at home (and I don't have access to such version of Firefox at work to test) - This is definitely something I have to deal with as soon as I can. What bothers me for the moment is the way Safari reacts with this new certificate... I would have expected at least a warning, or some kind of popup, but it simply ignores my request.

Comment: I changed my certificate authority, and now everything is working fine, so I guess this was the root of the problem... I still find it strange the way Safari reacted, but I really appreciate the help.